# Not Getting Proper Result From Counters in Proteus Simulation

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, logic-gates, proteus

**Circuit Description:** This circuit should works as a over counter. Which should  count from 0 to 5 then it will give the pulse to the next IC

**Problem :** I found a circuit from online where they build a MOD-6 counter . Their circuit working just fine. I am trying to build same circuit but mine is not working . its not counting from 0 to 5 moreover in the IC-74LS90 i can see there is not enough power going to Light test (BI,RBI,LT) pin

what is worng with my circuit

***Circuit That i found Online***
[image]

***Circuit which i made***
[image]

Comment: Check the ground and pinout of the 3rd display, seems swapped. Also what signal are you feeding it?

Comment: "its not counting from 0 to 5" So, how IS it counting? Please edit your question to give the information. "not enough power going to" What does that mean?  Is your 5 volt supply putting out less than 5 volts? And what are you using for your clock generator? If it's a mechanical switch, have you debounced it?